# Lenient Java 8 Date parsing

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

I'd like to parse '2015-10-01' with `LocalDateTime`. What I have to do is

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse('2015-10-01');
LocalDateTime localDateTime = localDateTime.of(localDate, LocalTime.MIN);
```

But I'd like to parse it in one pass like

```
// throws DateTimeParseException
LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.parse('2015-10-01', DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
```

Also a small difference of a string throws the exception as well.

```
// throws DateTimeParseException
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse("2015-9-5", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
```

Can I parse date strings leniently with Java 8 Date APIs?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to parse date String as `"2015-10-01"` and `"2015-9-5"` to `LocalDateTime` objects, you can build your own `DateTimeFormatter` using `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                        .appendPattern("yyyy")
                                        .appendLiteral('-')
                                        .appendValue(MONTH_OF_YEAR)
                                        .appendLiteral('-')
                                        .appendValue(DAY_OF_MONTH)
                                        .parseDefaulting(HOUR_OF_DAY, HOUR_OF_DAY.range().getMinimum())
                                        .parseDefaulting(MINUTE_OF_HOUR, MINUTE_OF_HOUR.range().getMinimum())
                                        .parseDefaulting(SECOND_OF_MINUTE, SECOND_OF_MINUTE.range().getMinimum())
                                        .parseDefaulting(NANO_OF_SECOND, NANO_OF_SECOND.range().getMinimum())
                                        .toFormatter();
System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse("2015-9-5", formatter));
System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse("2015-10-01", formatter));
```

The variable length of each field is handled by the call to [`appendValue(field)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendValue-java.time.temporal.TemporalField-). Quoting the Javadoc:

> The parser for a variable width value such as this normally behaves greedily, requiring one digit, but accepting as many digits as possible.

This means that it will be able to parse month and days formatted with 1 or 2 digits.

To construct a `LocalDateTime`, we also need to provide a `LocalTime` to this builder. This is done by using [`parseDefaulting(field, value)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#parseDefaulting-java.time.temporal.TemporalField-long-) for each field of a `LocalTime`. This method takes a field and a default value for that field if it is not present in the String to parse. Since, in our case, the time information will not be present in the String, the default values will be chosen, i.e. the minimum value for the range of valid values for that field (it is obtained by calling [`getMinimum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ValueRange.html#getMinimum--) to the [`ValueRange`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ValueRange.html) of that field; perhaps we could also hard-code 0 here).

---

In the event that the String to parse might contain time information, we can use optional sections of `DateTimeFormatter`, like this:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                        .appendPattern("yyyy")
                                        .appendLiteral('-')
                                        .appendValue(MONTH_OF_YEAR)
                                        .appendLiteral('-')
                                        .appendValue(DAY_OF_MONTH)
                                        .appendPattern("[ HH:mm]") // optional sections are surrounded by []
                                        .parseDefaulting(HOUR_OF_DAY, HOUR_OF_DAY.range().getMinimum())
                                        .parseDefaulting(MINUTE_OF_HOUR, MINUTE_OF_HOUR.range().getMinimum())
                                        .parseDefaulting(SECOND_OF_MINUTE, SECOND_OF_MINUTE.range().getMinimum())
                                        .parseDefaulting(NANO_OF_SECOND, NANO_OF_SECOND.range().getMinimum())
                                        .toFormatter();
System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse("2015-9-5", formatter));
System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse("2015-10-01", formatter));
System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse("2015-1-1 10:10", formatter));
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution for your particular use case is to define your own format. In this example even though I have specified a single `M` for the month in my pattern, and a single `d` for the day, it still parses both examples the same.

```
@Test
public void parsing_singleDigitDates_andDoubleDigitDates_areEqual()
{
    DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-M-d");

    LocalDate dt1 = LocalDate.parse("2015-09-05", fmt);
    LocalDate dt2 = LocalDate.parse("2015-9-5", fmt);

    Assert.assertEquals(dt1, dt2);
}
```

I decided to write this answer after seeing the code soup that `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` requires you to write in order to solve the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
    private static final DateTimeFormatter formatter =
                DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss").withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.LENIENT);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that's not what I wanted. For that, I have to provide the text in a right format. That's _lenient_ in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

**Parsing date and time**

To create a `LocalDateTime` object from a string you can use the static `LocalDateTime.parse()` method. It takes a string and a `DateTimeFormatter` as parameter. The `DateTimeFormatter` is used to specify the date/time pattern.

```
String str = "1986-04-08 12:00";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(str, formatter);
```

**Formatting date and time**

To create a formatted string out a `LocalDateTime` object you can use the format() method.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.of(1986, Month.APRIL, 8, 12, 30);
String formattedDateTime = dateTime.format(formatter); // "1986-04-08 12:30"
```

Note that there are some commonly used date/time formats predefined as constants in `DateTimeFormatter`. For example: Using `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME` to format the `LocalDateTime` instance from above would result in the string "1986-04-08T12:30:00".

The `parse`() and `format`() methods are available for all date/time related objects (e.g. LocalDate or ZonedDateTime)

Comment: I'm sorry but please read the question carefully. I'm not asking about the usage.