# Is DateTimeFormatter more strict than SimpleDateFormat? Parsing date with milliseconds

Tags: java, java-8

I have simple test case:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS";
  String date = "2017-01-15 15:15:15.5";

  SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
  DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern);
  FastDateFormat fastDateFormat = FastDateFormat.getInstance(pattern);
  try {
    System.out.println("SFD: " + simpleDateFormat.parse(date));
  }catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println("SDF failed");
  }
  try {
    System.out.println("DTF: " + dateTimeFormatter.parse(date));
  }catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println("DTF failed");
  }
  try {
    System.out.println("FDF: " + fastDateFormat.parse(date));
  }catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println("FDF failed");
  }
}
```

Output is like this:

```
SFD: Thu Jan 15 15:15:15 CET 1970
DTF failed
FDF: Thu Jan 15 15:15:15 CET 1970
```

According to the results, Java's 8 DateTimeFormatter is more strict then SimpleDateFormat. My question is why and in that case, what would be best approach to accept both dates with `.S` as millis or `.SSS`, like parsing multiple times with try/catch ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SimpleDateFormat`'s is not strict per default, because the property `lenient` is `true` per default.  But you can set the property `lenient` to false to make it strict.

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
simpleDateFormat.setLenient(false);
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern);
try {
    System.out.println("SFD: " + simpleDateFormat.parse(date));
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println("SDF failed");
}
try {
    System.out.println("DTF: " + dateTimeFormatter.parse(date));
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println("DTF failed");
}
```

The result will be then

```
SDF failed
DTF failed
```

See [DateFormat.parse(String, ParsePosition)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse-java.lang.String-java.text.ParsePosition-)

> By default, parsing is lenient: If the input is not in the form used by this object's format method but can still be parsed as a date, then the parse succeeds. Clients may insist on strict adherence to the format by calling setLenient(false).

Comment: Can I set leninent behavior for DTF?

Comment: @kamil Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32962417/lenient-java-8-date-parsing

Comment: Thanks, found that question but I thought that there's more fancy way of doing it

Answer (score 2):

You are basically asking why `SimpleDateFormat` accepts one digit millisecond values when the pattern says ".SSS".

The reason is in the javadoc for `SimpleDateFormat`:

> Pattern letters are usually repeated, as their number determines the exact presentation:
>
> ...
>
> Number: For formatting, the number of pattern letters is the minimum number of digits, and shorter numbers are zero-padded to this amount. For parsing, **the number of pattern letters is ignored** unless it's needed to separate two adjacent fields.

Apparently, you can change this by calling `setLenient(false)`.  However, the javadocs don't specify what the actual effect of leniency is.

By contrast, the javadoc for `DateTimeFormatter` simply says "the count of pattern letters determines the format", making no distinction between formatting and parsing.

---

Why are they different?  You would need to ask the people who designed the `DateTimeFormatter` API, but I imagine it was that the designers considered the *ad hoc* and unspecified nature of `SimpleDateFormat` (default) lenient parsing mode to be harmful.

---

How do you simply get `DateTimeFormatter` to accept dates with one or 3 digits millisecond values?

One approach would be to create the formatter using a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`.  This allows you to specify a minimum and maximum width for any field in the format.