# JDK7- SimpleDateFormat vs JDK8-DateTimeFormatter, "2019 02" is parsable with the old but not the new one

Tags: java-8

I am using the same format "yyyyMM" in SimpleDateFormat and DateTimeFormatter. I have set the leniency in both formatters.

Though, SimpleDateFormat is able to parse "2019 02" but not  DateTimeFormatter. I have tried setting multiple formatters but no luck.

It must be a simple way but I am not able to figure it own. Does any one know how to restore the behavior with DateTimeFormatter?

```
 String dateString = "2018-11";
  String format = "yyyyMM";

  SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
    simpleDateFormat.setLenient(true);
  try {
    Date parse = simpleDateFormat.parse(dateString);
    System.out.println(parse);
    System.out.println(format + ":parsed: true : java7");

    } catch (ParseException e) {
      System.out.println(format + ":parsed: false : java7");
    }
  DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format).withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.LENIENT);


  try {
        TemporalAccessor parse = formatter.parse(dateString);
        System.out.println(parse.toString());
        System.out.println(format + ": parsed: true : java11");


    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(format + ":parsed: false : java11");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Do you have an example we can run and see the difference for ourself? Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more details.

Comment: @nucandrei, updated the question.

Comment: 2018-11 clearly doesn't match yyyyMM. One contains a dash and not the other. Just use the correct pattern.

Comment: Why would SimpleDateFormat allow it? I want backward compatibility, changing the pattern is not an option.

Comment: You are comparing different methods.

Comment: Well if you can change your code, why couldn't you change the pattern it uses? Your code relied on a questionable "feature" of SimpleDateFormat and used an incorrect pattern. Do the right thing, and fix it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is DateTimeFormatter more strict than SimpleDateFormat? Parsing date with milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48783960/is-datetimeformatter-more-strict-than-simpledateformat-parsing-date-with-millis)

Comment: I hope, you are aware that the `SimpleDateFormat` returns an incorrect result. You are providing an input not matching the pattern and one method silently returns nonsensical data whereas the other reports the problem via an exception. Do you really want to keep the behavior of getting corrupt data? Then stay with the `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: @Holger, yes it is wrong but can't help. The damage is already caused as that was working before.  We want to move away from SimpleDateFormat because of better thread-safe formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a DateTimeFormatter with a complex pattern with a [DateTimeFormatterBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html):

For example to parse `yyyyMM`, `yyyy-MM` and `yyyy MM` you could use:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendValue(ChronoField.YEAR_OF_ERA, 4)
        .optionalStart().appendLiteral('-').optionalEnd()
        .optionalStart().appendLiteral(' ').optionalEnd()
        .appendValue(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, 2)
        .toFormatter();
```

But this format is also strict because the year and the month have a fixed width else the optional literals doesn't work.

You can add `.parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)` to simply parse a LocalDate.